# Aligning string inside listbox c#

Tags: c#, string, text, listbox, alignment

I'm trying to write `strings` with spaces into a listbox, and keep them aligned.

Here is the code:

```
    List<String> treeNames = new List<String>();
    int counter = 1;

    treeNames.Add("Input                ");
    treeNames.Add("Output               ");
    treeNames.Add("Sequence Type        ");

   foreach (String currentData in treeNames)
   {
         listBox1.Items.Add(currentData + " - " + counter.ToString());
         counter+=1;
   }
```

Here's what I hope to achieve:

```
Input                 - 1
Output                - 2
Sequence Type         - 3
```

Instead, I'm getting:

```
Input           - 1
Output               - 2
Sequence Type                   - 3
```

Any ideas how can I align them?

Comment: Is this WPF? Or WinForms?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a mono-spaced font?

Comment: this [thread][1] may help resolve your issue


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982807/c-sharp-insert-a-variable-number-of-spaces-into-a-string-formatting-an-outpu

Comment: Look at maybe using ListView.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.PadRight method which returns a new string that left-aligns the characters in the string by padding them with spaces on the right for a specified total length.

Let's say you have 20 character maximum length for a name:

```
public String stringHighscore()
{
     return name + name.PadRight(20 - name.Length) + "\t\t\t" + score.ToString();
}
```

If your name's length is 13, this will add 7 space characters. If your name's length is 9, this will add 11 space characters. That way all your name's lengths will equal 20 at the end.

Comment: Ok, it worked! Thanks. Now, I'm trying to add the same formatted string into a TreeView node, but for some reason they are completely aligned, even with the solution you presented, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (String currentData in treeNames)
{
     listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0, -20} {1, 10}", currentData, ("-  " + counter.ToString())));
     counter += 1;
}
```